# MongoDB missing items from Schema

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm creating an application where i use MongoDB as my database with mongoose.

I created several models in my application, user and blog articles models work flawlessly , but this one model for collaborators does not display anything even though it was made exactly like the other models.

[Here you can see what i get whenever i call 'colabPosts'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq8mP.png)

This is the collaborators model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const colabSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  image: [
    {
      url: String,
      filename: String,
    },
  ],
  category: String,
  description: String,
  link: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Colab', colabSchema);
```

These are the routes and where i use that 'colabPosts' variable.

```
const Colab = require("../models/colab");
const Blog = require('../models/blog');
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const { isLoggedIn } = require("../loggedInMiddleware");
const multer = require("multer");
const { storage } = require("../cloudinary/cldindex");
const upload = multer({ storage });

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const blogPosts = await Blog.find({});
  const colabPosts = await Colab.find({});
  res.render("colab/index", { colabPosts , blogPosts});
  console.log(colabPosts)
});

router.get("/new", async(req, res) => {
  res.render("colab/new");
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const colabNew = new Colab(req.body.colab);
  await colabNew.save();
  res.redirect("/colab");
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the form for new collaborators

```
        <form action="/colab" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
              <img src="../../images/wagecn.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>
          
            <div class="container">
              <label for="Title"><b>Titlul postarii</b></label>
              <input type="text" id="title" name="colab[title]" required>

              <label for="Category"><b>Categoria</b></label>
              <input type="text" id="category" name="colab[category]" required>

              <label for="link"><b>Link</b></label>
              <input type="text" id="link" name="colab[link]" required>
          
              <label for="description"><b>Descriere si imagine</b></label>
              <textarea  id="description" name="colab[description]" required></textarea>

              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image" multiple>
            </div>
                  
              <button>Adauga Colaborator</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And the index where all collaborators should appear with title description and links

```
 <% for(let colab in colabPosts){ %> 
      <div class="six columns class1">
        <div class="classic-collaborators">
          <div class="classic-collaborators-ux">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="upload/primaria.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="300" /></div>
               <div class="classic-content">
                  <h3 class="title"><%= colab.title %> </h3>
                  <div class="info">
                     <div class="info-tag"><span class="info-head ">Tags </span><a href="#" rel="tag"><%= colab.category %> </a></div>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="excerpt"><%= colab.description %> </div>
                       <a href="<%= colab.link %> " class="readMore">Viziteaza</a>     
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
               </div>
              <% } %>
```

I can't seem to find the mistake that [returns objects to not have title or description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSEWS.png)